# Thread Line is missing on Outlook 2016

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2016

I have recently upgraded from Outlook 2010 to Outlook 2016 and one of my favourite features disappeared. When I clicked on an e-mail, a line indicating which of the e-mails were included in the thread would appear. Screenshot from Outlook 2010:

[image: img]

In Office 2016, this line disappeared and I can't figure out the thread flow at a glance. Was this feature removed, how can I bring it back?

**Edit:**

I'm already using 'Show as Conversations' but thread line is missing:

[image: img]

Comment: View > Show as Conversations

Comment: [View email messages by conversation - Outlook](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/view-email-messages-by-conversation-0eeec76c-f59b-4834-98e6-05cfdfa9fb07)

Comment: @DavidPostill Please check my edit.

Comment: Try in *View > Conversation Settings* to set "Use Classic Indented View".

Comment: @harrymc Indentation changed but still no thread lines.

Answer (score 0):

The thread line has been removed since Outlook 2013. Check the thread below which discusses a similar question in Outlook 2013:
[How to enable mail trail lines in Outlook 2013 conversation view](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/75e85330-35f2-4d45-aa7a-0a2f14cbecf3/how-can-i-remove-message-indent-lines?forum=outlook)

Given this situation, personally I'd like to suggest submitting a feedback to [the Outlook UserVoice forum](https://outlook.uservoice.com/) if you want this feature to be added back.